# Why these Surahs are used to perform Ruqyah - Surat al-Kaafirun, Surat al-Ikhlas, Surat al-A’araf, Surat Yoonus, Surat Ta-Ha

Tags: quran, hadith, reference-request, sihr

I was searching for Ways of Treating Magic. I found an answer in [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/12918)

It said we should read

> "Surat al-Fatihah, Ayat al-Kursiy, Surat al-A’araf verse 106-122, Surat Yoonus verse 79-82, Surat Ta-Ha verse 65-69, Surat al-Kaafirun, Surat al-Ikhlas and al-Mu’awwadhatayn."

However, it did not mention **Why these Ayats are used to perform Ruqyah.**

As far I know "Surat al-Fatihah, Ayat al-Kursiy, and al-Mu’awwadhatayn" is very important to protect from bad stuff.

But I could not find anything regarding reading "Surat al-Kaafirun, Surat al-Ikhlas, Surat al-A’araf verse 106-122, Surat Yoonus verse 79-82, Surat Ta-Ha verse 65-69" to perform ruqyah.

Can you please give reference to these Surahs and Ayats to be recited to perform ruqyah. Or, at least explain when these Surahs and Ayats are prescribed by the sheikhs to perform ruqyah or cure Magic.

**Update 1**

Upon further reading on [alifta.com](http://www.alifta.com/fatawa/fatawasubjects.aspx?languagename=en&View=Page&HajjEntryID=0&HajjEntryName=&RamadanEntryID=0&RamadanEntryName=&NodeID=3868&PageID=123&SectionID=8&SubjectPageTitlesID=15619&MarkIndex=0&0), I found that

> All the Glorious Qur'an is blessed and can be recited as Ruqyah.
>   Al-Fatihah (Opening Chapter of the Qur'an), Ayat-ul-Kursy, Surah
>   Al-Ikhlas and Al-Mu`awwidhatayn can be recited as Ruqyah

I am still to find out why Surat al-Ikhlas and Surat al-Kaafirun are specifically prescribed for Ruqyah.

Answer (score 4):

All Quranic verses on the topic of sihr are effective weapons against it.

[Surat al-A’araf verse 106-122](https://quran.com/7/106-122)
[Surat Yoonus verse 79-82](https://quran.com/10/79-82)
[Surat Ta-Ha verse 65-69](https://quran.com/20/65-79)

Are all about Moses defeating Pharaoh's magicians and several thousand magicians falling down in prostration in awe of Allah's power, so naturally they are included.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: And why Surat al-Kaafirun & Surat al-Ikhlas are used to perform Ruqyah? Is there any reference for these two Surats?

Comment: @blueray hm as for surat al-Ikhlas finding evidences the matter is easy.

Comment: @Sassir can you please direct me to the evidence why Surat al-Ikhlas is used to perform Ruqyah

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly answer your question, but as far as I've looked it up, there are very few resources about recommending those verses against sihr. Instead, there are several resources in sunnah which recommend the two Surats: Falaq and Nas, as well as -of course Tohid.

For example in Al-Tirmidhi ([2058](http://sunnah.com/urn/673610)) it says:

> The Prophet (PBUH) was constantly seeking safety and guard from God against Jinn and bad eyes and bad things, until the Lord gave him Mauzat (i.e. Falaq and Nas) and so he kept up these verses afterwards and quit the others.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Do you have any online resource for that hadith I was not able to find it so far.

Comment: Alaikom-al-salam @Medi1Saif . Yes I have, but it's in Persian and on the bottom of [this page](http://imuslimguide.com/fa/azkar/3)

Comment: Added a link with a better translation! Note my understanding of the question is that OP is more looking for references for the verses from the other surahs that put them in relation to sihr/ruqya.

Comment: Thanks @Medi1Saif and God bless. As I said in the beginning, this was not a direct answer. And my personal impression is, Mauzat is more than enough for protection against those stuff.

Comment: @polfosol The link you provided grade the Hadith as Da'if.

Comment: @blueray see for example in ([Riadu as-Saliheen](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/16/49)) it is acceptable to rely on da'if hadith in case of a good matter and as long as it is not a worship, but it is better to declare it being da'if. Most of the referneces you may find on your inquiry will hardly be stronger than hassen or hassan li ghayrih (a da'if hadith that can only be strengthen due to other similar narrations)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Can I really use a daif hadith to abandon all other amal for seeking safety and guard from Allah against Jinn and bad eyes and bad things?

Comment: I am not an Alim. I trust people who seem to give reference, and present both side of the argument before making their point. I found islamqa to be one of those sites. They have an article regarding [daif hadith](https://islamqa.info/en/44877). Here, you will find all different side of the argument. Just so that you know, I choose to take the opinion of al-Albaani which is `it is not permissible to act on the basis of a weak hadeeth at all, whether with regard to virtuous deeds or otherwise`.

Comment: @blueray Actually, the amount of hadith supporting my argument are much more than that and there are several _hasan_ hadiths in that regard. The trouble was, I couldn't find suitable references in _English_ and I am not a great translator. So I thought it's better to stick to an easily translatable one; and even so, I didn't do a great job apparently ;P

Comment: @polfosol I just want the truth. If you know of any Sahih or Hasan Hadith then just give the reference. Fula Fula book and Fula Fula Hadith no. I will In-Shah-Allah translate it with a local Sheikh. And, **definitely you did a great job**, at least you tried to help me. I just think upvote/downvote/accept button in this site is a Amanah. As, I am not a scholar, I try not to hit it. It is just my paranoia.

Comment: @blueray I will try and find some Arabic references later. In the meantime, [there is a page in Persian](http://quran.anhar.ir/fazilat-346.htm) and the references therein, which lists several hadiths about this.